# Prevent NavigationLink in VStack from being highlighted when tapped

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

When navigation link is used inside a VStack, it becomes semi-transparent (highlighted) when tapped. **Is it possible to prevent such behavior?**

```
NavigationView {
    ScrollView {
        VStack() {
            NavigationLink() {
                MyView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provided code snapshot does not demo what you described. By default `NavigationLink` highlights on touch and not become transparent.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using a NavigationLink; in that case you can style it with a .buttonStyle() modifier. I'm not very versed in the current SwiftUI API but, at the first blush, all the included button styles do the highlighting, hence a new button style might be required that doesn't do it. I can post it in an answer if you need code.

Comment: thanks for the response, I edited my question to clarify what I meant

Comment: Any Progress on this one so far?